# Cassandra node uptime since UN state

Tags: cassandra

I joined a new Cassandra node to my existing cluster and, as expected, it took quite a while to join (UJ state) as the DB yields great amounts of information. The next day I realised that the join process was complete, but I don't know when it completed. In other words, my question is: is there a way to determine when the novel node changed from UJ state to UN state?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see that in the logs with the corresponding timestamps. When your node started to join:

> JOINING: waiting for ring information

when the node has done joining, you should see:

> Node /a.b.c.d state jump to NORMAL

Comment: debug.log,  one of the compressed ones